# Excel table to django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to move from excel based form submissions to a web form, but having a problem to figuring out how to store a summary table (from excel) to a database. Excel table, which is submitted quarterly looks like this:

```
    |total|at x|at y|other x|other y|
----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+
LD1 |     |    |    |       |       |
LD2 |     |    |    |       |       |
CD1 |     |    |    |       |       |
CD2 |     |    |    |       |       |
----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+
```

and I have a problem converting it into a model. I am thinking to create a choice type (LD1, LD2..) for the first column, iterate over those choices and create 4 forms with the choice already filled. My first question - is it the way to go or is there a better way to store this kind of information? Second - how to create those 4 forms, that have first field as a non input (read-only) field?

Comment: You can create a table in your html file and add inputs for columns you want. You can use a model for row names, and calculate total columns on input changes. You can store data in another model which referenced (Foreign Key) to rows. Using two model is clearer solution I think.

Comment: Could you give an example? RowNamesModel with col - label (weight to keep order) and DataModel with cols - row_name_id, total, at_x, at_y, other_x, other_y something like that? What did you mean by "calculate total columns on input changes"?

Comment: Yes, RowNamesModel with col, label, etc. fields and DataModel with row_name_id, at_x, at_y, other_x, other_y and a property total which returns sum of at_x, at_y, other_x and other_y. In your html file, you can update total (read-only field) by input value changes with some little javascript code. You can store only values for at_x, at_y, other_x and other_y in your DataModel. (total can be calculated as a property)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Total is a bit misleading here, it has to be editable, as a person entering data might know only total, but not separate instances. I had a problem figuring out how to store row titles.